# Creating Membership Tables in MVC4 and VS2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

I am new to MVC, i created new empty template project started with the development, now i want to integrate membership in my project, i followed steps from [Adding AspNet SimpleMembership to an Existing MVC4 Project](http://monox.mono-software.com/blog/post/Mono/226/Adding-ASP-NET-SimpleMembership-to-an-existing-MVC-4-application/)
After making appropriate changes when i build the project and run the site, i got following error:

```
Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
```

I googled around to see the solution and also refered SO questions, but they all had a same resolution to remove duplicate `<DbProviderFactories />` but in my case i didn't had any duplicate entry in my

```
/Windows/Microsoft.Net/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Config/machine.config
```

Does anyone has faced this issue, any Suggestions ?